# Migration from SHA1 to SHA2 ASP.net 4.5, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sha

We have one ASP.NET web application which is built in .NET Framework 4.5 version. Currently on production this application is using SHA1 encryption algorithm. This algorithm is set in "MachineKey" tag of application's web.config file. This application uses ASP.Net Membership concept for maintaining Login credentials.

As the SHA1 algorithm is on verge of degradation so we want to update our application from SHA1 to SHA2. For this we have set "HMACSHA256" in "MachineKey" tag of application's web.config file.

After upgrading our application to SHA2 with the above settings, we expect that the older user's passwords (which were encrypted using SHA1 and already present in membership database) will not work with SHA2 algorithm. But it allows older users to login without any modification in previously encrypted password.

Question 1: Are the changes made in "MachineKey" tag of application's web.config file enough/recommended for this migration?

Question 2: As we are still able to login into the application using previously encrypted passwords, does the membership database really uses the SHA2 encryption set in web.config file? Or we need to add some additional settings to enable SHA2 encryption on membership database level? Please advice.

Please suggest if there is any best way to enable SHA2 encryption on Membership database level.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is possible to handle such a migration with Membership, without forcing users to go through a password reset process.

But you can do that by migrating Membership to Asp.Net Identity at the same time: Asp.Net Identity has extension points allowing you to handle a "fallback" password signature match for supporting old signature. At that point, you still have the login and password unhashed in memory, and you can then by the way convert the signature to the new format.

All that is explained with details and code in following [blog](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity), including the SQL migration I am only slightly explain in an added comment in below code.

Here is the main class for achieving this:

> ```
> public class BackCompatPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher
> {
>     public override string HashPassword(string password)
>     {
>         return base.HashPassword(password);
>     }
>
>     public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(
>         string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
>     {
>         // Relies on SQL migration having formatted old hashes as
>         // (aspnet_Membership.Password + '|' + 
>         // CAST(aspnet_Membership.PasswordFormat as varchar) + '|'
>         // + aspnet_Membership.PasswordSalt)
>         string[] passwordProperties = hashedPassword.Split('|');
>         if (passwordProperties.Length != 3)
>         {
>             return base.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, 
>                 providedPassword);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             string passwordHash = passwordProperties[0];
>             int passwordformat = 1;
>             string salt = passwordProperties[2];
>             if (String.Equals(EncryptPassword(providedPassword,
>                 passwordformat, salt), 
>                 passwordHash, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
>             {
>                 return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     //This is copied from the existing SQL providers and is provided only 
>     // for back-compat.
>     private string EncryptPassword(string pass, int passwordFormat, 
>          string salt)
>     {
>         if (passwordFormat == 0) // MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear
>             return pass;
>
>         byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
>         byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
>         byte[] bRet = null;
>
>         if (passwordFormat == 1)
>         { // MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed 
>             HashAlgorithm hm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
>             if (hm is KeyedHashAlgorithm)
>             {
>                 KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = (KeyedHashAlgorithm)hm;
>                 if (kha.Key.Length == bSalt.Length)
>                 {
>                     kha.Key = bSalt;
>                 }
>                 else if (kha.Key.Length < bSalt.Length)
>                 {
>                     byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
>                     Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, 0, bKey.Length);
>                     kha.Key = bKey;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
>                     for (int iter = 0; iter < bKey.Length; )
>                     {
>                         int len = Math.Min(bSalt.Length, bKey.Length - iter);
>                         Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, iter, len);
>                         iter += len;
>                     }
>                     kha.Key = bKey;
>                 }
>                 bRet = kha.ComputeHash(bIn);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
>                 Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
>                 Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
>                 bRet = hm.ComputeHash(bAll);
>             }
>         }
>
>         return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
>     }
> }
> ```

Then, in your user manager:

```
public class IdentityUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>
{
    public IdentityUserManager(IUserStore<IdentityUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        PasswordHasher = new BackCompatPasswordHasher();
    }
}
```

In my actual code base, I have some additions for handling re-hashing but unfortunately, no comments on why. Maybe that was some superfluous code from original implementer, or it was really needed. I have not investigate it, so here is the additional code in IdentityUserManager:

```
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> UserRehashed = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    private bool CanRehash(IdentityUser user)
    {
        return UserRehashed.TryAdd(user.Id, user.Id);
    }

    protected async override Task<bool> VerifyPasswordAsync(
        IUserPasswordStore<IdentityUser, string> store, IdentityUser user,
        string password)
    {
        var hash = await store.GetPasswordHashAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var verifPassRes = PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hash, password);
        if (verifPassRes == PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded &&
            // avoid rehash loop.
            CanRehash(user))
        {
            var chPassRes = await this.ChangePasswordAsync(user.Id,
                password, password).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!chPassRes.Succeeded)
            {
                // throw or log, whatever.
            }
        }

        return verifPassRes != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With my [other answer](/a/37221431/1178314) technical details, I just realize why you can change hashing algorithm without causing old password to get "lost".

Membership does store the hashing algorithm it has used with each password, thus allowing it to still validates old password after a hash algorithm change.

This explains the behavior you have seen. To double check it (and infirms your question 1 & 2 concerns), inspect your data in db, check the `PasswordFormat` column which should change depending on the used hash algorithm.

You should also check if simply logging in with an old account is enough to have it re-hashed to SHA-2 by Membership. If this is the case, all regular users will be re-hashed quickly after having done the change.

<sub>I do not remove my previous answer since it may still be helpful if one considers migrating the authentication framework too.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of upgrading from **SHA1** to **SHA2** is to actually decrease your known security issue of SHA1 which was hacked many years ago.  So to try and have a hybrid system is mostly pointless.

Short Term:   99% of users are on SHA1 ..   and only NEW users  1% of all users are on SHA2  ??  :(

**You just need to enforce the password change which makes 100% of people on SHA2**

Comment: The SHA1 vulnerability is about the possibility of generating "collisions": from a different content, obtaining the same signature. Exploiting a SHA1 collision on a login password internal signature is to my knowledge still not done, and will very probably never be done, because collisions generation technics require lengthy inputs which should be forbidden by login/password inputs.

Comment: @Frédéric    I was reading about these "collision" and i'm not sure that I really am understanding the problem that well.

Comment: Collision principle is to alter some content (such as a file download, for adding in it some malware, or a certificate, ...) but in a manner its SHA-1 hash will remain the same, luring security systems relying on SHA-1 signature. This was done numerous times with MD5 hashes, and SHA-1 has the same vulnerability (more and more accessible, some years ago it was still requiring huge computing power). Thus the ending of SHA-1 signed certificate occurring in 2017. About privately held SHA-1 signatures such as hashed password inside a DB, exploiting the vulnerability is another matter.